# How to setup PHP server in production?

Tags: php, ssh, webserver, port, vps

I use  php -S 127.0.0.1:4242 command to start development server on localhost for php files. But I guess, I shouldn't use this thing in production. Currently I'm trying to setup my website on VPS and I don't know how to start php server forever using ssh on port 4242. I know, this is probably very dumb question, this is my first time I work with real hosting

Would be grateful to any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup virtual host so that it should run always.

Here is a full [doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) of setup guide on server.

Comment: joe brock > For what reason have you downvote this response?

Comment: I didn't :) someone else did. Upvoted.